# Wordpress hook that gets featured image from direct URL?

Tags: hooks, post-thumbnails, post-editor

I use a lot of plugins on my site so I'm trying to minimize the amount more plugins.

I was wondering if there's a wordpress hook I can **use so that I can use an image that is hosted on imageshack and use that as a featured image** *without* having the image saved on my wordpress site?

Is that even possible? This sounds like a really complicated request. lol

Comment: This can be done but at least you have to save the URL of image somewhere, may be post meta!

Comment: please write more details, inserting post in default way or by front-end form ?
if u used your form so you can save url of image as post meta like @Sumit said

Comment: @Sumit I use imageshack, or maybe I don't understand what you mean???

Comment: Please check the @iantsch answer, I meant the same.

Answer (score 6):

### First try: A bad one

Have you tried this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/upload-image-from-a-url-and-assign-it-as-a-featured-image-to-a-custom-post-type)? With a few adaptions it should work for your question too.

### Second try: A real approach with a solution!

If you want to use an URL based featured image, without saving the image file in your WordPress installation, but still use the implemented WordPress functions within your Theme/Plugin, you need to know how media in WP is represented:

> When you upload a file, WordPress does not reference the image or file
>   using its URL, it uses an attachment. Attachments are posts of type
>   attachment, and are referred to by their post ID. For example, when
>   you set a featured image on a post, it stores your chosen image's post
>   ID in that post's meta `_thumbnail_id`.

Source: http://www.wptherightway.org/en/post_types/index.html (2016-03-14 01:23 UTC)

**Conclusion:** URL based featured images are not foreseen in the WP enviroment.

If you still wanna achieve it, there are 3 simple steps:

1. Filter the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` result, to allow the url strings as `_thumbnail_id` instead of `post_id`.

   ```
   function my_get_attachment_image_src($image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon){
       if (empty($attachment_id)) return $image;
       if (
           (string) intval($attachment_id) != (string) $attachment_id && 
           $attachment_id != ''
       ) {
           $image[0]= $attachment_id;
       }
       return $image;
   }

   add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'my_get_attachment_image_src', 10, 4);
   ```
2. Create an additional meta box for posts and pages to show and set the URL based featured images.

   ```
   function add_my_meta_box() {
       add_meta_box(
           'post_thumbnail_url',
           __('External URL as featured Image'),
           'my_meta_box',
           'post',
           'side',
           'low'
       );
       add_meta_box(
           'page_thumbnail_url',
           __('External URL as featured Image'),
           'my_meta_box',
           'page',
           'side',
           'low'
       );
   }

   function my_meta_box($post) {
       $attachment_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
       if (
           (string) intval($attachment_url) != (string) $attachment_url && 
           $attachment_url != ''
       ) {
           echo "<img width='100%' id='my_thumbnail_preview' src='{$attachment_url}'>";
       }
       $placeholder = __('e.g. http://foo.bar/image.jpg');
       echo "<input type='text' placeholder='{$placeholder}' name='my_thumbnail_url' id='my_thumbnail_url' value='{$attachment_url}'>";
   }

   add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_my_meta_box');
   ```
3. Add a `save_post` filter to handle the post meta `_thumbnail_id` (= Featured Image ID/URL).

   ```
   function save_my_thumbnail_url($post_id) {
       if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
           return;
       if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
           return;
       if ($_POST['my_thumbnail_url'] && !empty($_POST['my_thumbnail_url'])) {
           update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $_POST['my_thumbnail_url']);
   }
       //TODO: Handle empty featured image url.
   }

   add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_thumbnail_url', 99);
   ```

Now you can use the URL based featured image in your theme.

```
the_post_thumbnail();
// or…
$image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID());
echo "<img src='{$image_url}'>"
```

Comment: @Sumit i edited my answer, please remove down vote if you think this might answer the question accordingly

Comment: A sidenote iantsch, your original answer was just a link, your answer needs to contain the answer, links die, bitrot sets in, and your answer needs to stand on its own. External links can support it, but they can't be the answer itself.

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't download the image, so I don't think @Sumit 's comment is accurate here as it currently stands. The answer could be improved with some information explaining how a featured thumbnail is stored as an attachment ID in post meta, as well as some basics on how media in WP is represented

Comment: @TomJNowell i improved the answer with some more information.